# VsCode Remote SSH .vscode-server taking up a lot of space

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I got an alert this morning for disk space in `/home` on a multi user remote SSH dev environment server.

Running `partition -$xdev -type f -ls | sort -k 7 -r -n | head -20` I saw that the largest directories are `.vscode-server` with space nearing almost 1GB.

```sh
974M    .
10:06:16 my_user@my_server .vscode-server → pwd
/home/my_user/.vscode-server
10:08:06 my_user@my_server .vscode-server →
```

```sh
29459 38028 -rwxr-xr-x   1 my_user  my_user  38940504 Aug 15 11:17 ./my_user/.vscode-server/bin/some_hash/node
26270 38028 -rwxr-xr-x   1 my_user  my_user  38940504 Sep  3 16:51 ./my_user/.vscode-server/bin/some_other_hash/node
24078 38028 -rwxr-xr-x   1 my_user  my_user  38940504 Oct 15 10:34 ./my_user/.vscode-server/bin/yet_another_hash/node
2387 38028 -rwxr-xr-x   1 my_user  my_user  38940504 Oct  9 01:58 /home/my_user/.vscode-server/bin/last_hash/node
```

Looking through the directories it looks like this is where a lot of VsCode lives on the remote server and where remote extensions are installed to.

Does anyone know if there is any safe files that can be cleaned up in `.vscode-server` or is just adding more space to `/home` the solution.

Comment: Found this documentation that might be relevant, but looks like it is for a single user: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_cleaning-up-the-vs-code-server-on-the-remote

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From my practice, you can delete the .vscode-server directory to free space. Next time you log in to this server, the system will automatically install another .vscode-server which tends to be much smaller than the original one.

Answer (score 14):

There seem to be several parts to this...

Before you start removing things, you should remove any `vscode-server` processes.

I used this to find them...

```
ps ax | grep -i code
```

`bin/UUID` - these are the actual binaries. In theory, you can remove old ones but I'm not sure how to find out which one is current. If you remove them all, VSCode will install the current version for you the next time it connects.

`data/User/workspaceStorage` - this is the (apparently infamous) workspace that can grow huge. You can remove all of these, and they'll be re-created as needed.

`data/logs` - these are safe to remove

`extensions` - You can't just remove these if you want to have them available! (vscode treats remove vs local extensions differently). However, I did notice at least one extension with 2 versions installed, so maybe check for that and remove old versions?

There's more files in there... but these were the only sizeable ones in my `.vscode-server` directory.

Comment: There is a file 'package.json' in all of the bin/UUID folders, so you can use `grep -H version */package.json` to find out

Answer (score 3):

That's right, it really takes up a lot of space.
I noticed today that it occupies 1.4TB.
It was utterly contemptible. I delete the **.vscode-server directory every day at 4 am using crontab**

Answer (score 1):

Its better to create symlinks to the directory in to your partitions which has more space.

I generally prefer the following (/local/mnt is on a partition which has more space available).

ln -s /local/mnt/workspace/X-server   /home//.vscode-server

ln -s /local/mnt/workspace/X   /home//.vscode